# How to validate checkbox with useArrayField and yup

Tags: nuxt.js, yup, vee-validate

## Issue

I'd like to set validation for following input with Nuxt3, but couldn’t.

## component

```
<template>
  <form method="" action="" @submit="onSubmit">
    <ul class="form_radio_list">
      <li
        v-for="(employmentType, index) in mastersStore.masters?.EmploymentTypeCodes"
        :key="employmentType.code"
      >
        <label class="form_checkbox_label">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="employment_type_codes"
            v-model="employmentTypes"
            :value="employmentType.code"
          />
          <p class="form_checkbox_text">{{ employmentType.name }}</p>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</template>
```

## Script

```
<script>
    import { useForm, useField, useFieldArray } from 'vee-validate'
    import { useMastersStore } from '~~/store/master'
    import type { UpdateUserConditionForEmailInput } from '~~/types/user_condition_for_email'
    import * as yup from 'yup'

    const validationSchema = yup.object({
        employment_type_codes: yup.array().min(1, '雇用形態は必須です'),
    })

    const { fields: employmentTypes } = useFieldArray('employment_type_codes')
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((params: UpdateUserConditionForEmailInput): void => {
        props.goToConfirm(params)
    })
</script>
```

Based on README, I tried some kinds of array schema, but didn’t work.
https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/README.md#arrayoftype-schema-this

In this yup setting, the validation didn’t work even if I input nothing

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    employment_type_codes: yup.array().of(
        yup.object().shape({
            employmentTypes: yup.boolean().required('雇用形態は必須です'),
        })
    ),
})
```

This returned same result

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
      employment_type_codes: yup.array().required('雇用形態は必須です'),
})
```

When I use min() schema, I could validate when input empty.
But I can’t submit even if input checkboxes.

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    employment_type_codes: yup.array().required(1, '雇用形態は必須です'),
})
```

---

When checked the type of "employmentTypes", it was Object type.
The type of "employmentTypes.value" was array.

Comment: I believe you should do something like this: `employment_type_codes: yup.array().test("validation-name", "error message", (employmentTypeCodes) => { do the checks on your array here and return true if OK })`